# Каков предел нагрузки iptables?

Tags: iptables

На уровне приложения разруливать разрешённые и запрещённые адреса видится неправильным и хочется возложить эту работу на iptables.

Вопрос: iptables потребляет ресурсы CPU, может быть такое что при возрастании количества запросов сервер заткнётся из-за правил iptables? Есть ориаенировочные данные сколько запросов может разрулить какое железо? Или ширина канала с любом случае быстрее закончится и к серверу запрос просто не пробъётся из-за их количества?

Comment: В бане iptables через fail2ban висит тысячи две адресов. Полет нормальный. CentOS 7, nginx, 2ГБ памяти.

Comment: @KAGGDesign но ведь для чего-то ipsets придумали? Кстати, вы уверены что ваш fail2ban их не использует?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, я читал, что ipset быстрее. Но fail2ban пишет в iptables. Я это вижу в iptables -L    а вот ipset list дает пустой ответ.

Comment: @PavelMayorov  О, чего нашел: https://lawsonry.com/2015/01/automatically-block-banned-ips-with-fail2ban-iptables-and-ipset/  сейчас попробую. Давно хотел переключиться на ipset

Comment: запустил скрипт подсчета - 4100 адресов в блоке на данный момент.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

За нагрузку можно сильно не беспокоится, в случае если в одной цепочке iptables не сильно больше 1000 правил. Ядро обрабатывает каждую цепочку, на которую попало управление, строго последовательно. Из за этого перебор большого количества правил начнет тормозить. Если правил предполагается значительно более 1000 то придумайте алгоритм для их разбиения на несколько цепочек, каждая из которых вызывается только для определенного вида пакетов или определенного диапазона ip. Например, разбейте правила по подсетям:

```
iptables -N RULE_10
iptables -A RULE_10 -s 10.0.0.1 -j DROP
iptables -A RULE_10 -s 10.0.10.41 -j DROP
...
iptables -N RULE_192
iptables -A RULE_192 -s 192.168.0.1 -j DROP
iptables -A RULE_192 -s 192.168.50.48 -j DROP
...

iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j RULE_10
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.0.0.0/8 -j RULE_192
```

По похожей схеме (правда более сложной из за неравномерного распределения кол-ва правил по подсетям) у меня спокойно обрабатываются 35000 правил. Используется 3-х уровневая система цепочек, на верхнем и 2м уровне которой примерно по 30 правил, на 3 уровне в среднем 50-200 правил.

Но такую сложную схему пришлось использовать только по тому, что на той машине довольно старое ядро, которое менять не хочется и нет возможности использовать гораздо **более лучшее решение**:

Модуль iptables **ipset**. Данный модуль состоит из двух частей, собственно модуля для iptables и отдельной утилиты управления [ipset](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ipset). Суть сводится к тому, что если у нас однотипные правила, которые фильтруют по ip-адресу или например по номерам портов, мы создаем списки с помощью этой самой утилиты. А в самом iptables добавляется буквально одно правило вроде:

```
ipset create mailBlock hash:ip >/dev/null 2>&1
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set mailBlock src -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
```

В сам список можно заносить множество ip-адресов, их обработка на уровне ядра работает не перебором, а через хеш-таблицы, что очень быстро.

Comment: Ответ супер, спасибо. Вопрос: как правильно называются и где почитать про поведенческие правила (слышал такие можно делать), например: если с одного ip поступило более 10 запросов в секунду, то заблокировать все запросы с него на 30 минут.

Comment: @marrk2 Это делается модулями hashlimit и connlimit ищется в гугле по этим ключевым словам. ну или в сложных случаях, если количество пакетов не показатель, руками/скриптами. вот там вверху в комментах писали что используют какой то fail2ban (он по логам apache).

Comment: @mike не только apache. У меня nginx стоит вместе с fail2ban.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, Mike, да и не только nginx. собственно, можно мониторить любой лог-файл. и влиять можно не только на таблицы netfilter-а.

Comment: “По похожей схеме (правда более сложной из за неравномерного распределения кол-ва правил по подсетям)“ Спасибо за скрипт. А можно узнать, какие более сложные правила для маски подсети?

Comment: @STEEP Сначала подряд идущие, без разрывов, ip собираем в диапазоны, потом диапазоны нарезаем так, что бы в одной группе были ip с одинаковым двоичным логарифмом от самого ip. Логарифм как раз кол-во бит в маске. потом он разбивается так же, но уже нет требования что бы разрывов не было, тут как раз строятся цепочки 2 уровня, смотрим на кол-во правил в цепочках и уменьшаем маску по биту пока не превысит предел. В итоге диапазоны где мало адресов собираются чуть ли ни с маской /4, там где много до /20. Вот Perl скрипт который грузил правила https://pastebin.com/jXZCLaJf

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос общий. Ответ тоже общий.

Читал статью от CloudFlare о блокировке 10_000_000 пакетов в секунду,

Общий перевод ключевых моментов:

**Тестовый стендв**

Мы покажем кое-какие цифры, что бы проиллюстрировать наш метод. Воспользуемся одним из наших Intel серверов с 10Gbs сетевой картой. Железная часть не столь важна, ибо хотим показать работу ОС а не производительность железа.

Описание процесса тестирования:

- мы передает большое количество маленьких UDP пакетов (до 14Vpps)
- это трафик направляется на одиночный процессор на целевом сервере
- мы измеряем количество отфильтрованный (отброшенных) пакетов ядром

**Результат**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Источник**

- https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-drop-10-million-packets/